# configuration space of Riemannian manifolds with a parameter on the distance of distinct points

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, cohomology, configuration-spaces

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. For any $\epsilon\geq 0$, we define the $k$-th ($k=1,2,\cdots$) *"$\epsilon$-configuration space"* as
$$
F(M,k,\epsilon)=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in M^k\mid d(x_i, x_j)>\epsilon \text{ whenever }i\neq j\}
$$
and the $k$-th ($k=1,2,\cdots$) *"**unordered** $\epsilon$-configuration space"* as
$$
B(M,k,\epsilon)=F(M,k,\epsilon)/S_k=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_k)\in M^k\mid  d(x_i, x_j)>\epsilon\text{ whenever }i\neq j\}/S_k
$$
where $S_k$ is the symmetric group of order $k$ acting on $M^k$ by permuting the order of  coordinates.

We notice that $F(\mathbb{R}^n,k,\epsilon)=F(\mathbb{R}^n,k,0)$, but $F(S^n,k,\epsilon)\neq F(S^n,k,0)$ for $S^n$ the $n$-sphere.

**Question:**  are there any references for the cohomology ring 
$$
H^*(B(M,k,\epsilon);\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

Comment: Kahle and MacPherson have some results about the cohomology of these configuration spaces, though I don't think they've written them up.  It might be worth emailing Kahle about this.